# Is there better way for client app not to keep polling server for updates every 30 seconds and without GCM or FCM

Tags: android

**Current Implementation:**

I've tried using a `Handler` and `Runnable` to handle the timing mechanism for posting to the server. However, the `postDelay` time went from 2 minutes to 7 minutes when the device is asleep.

Also, tried firing `IntentService` directly from `AlarmManager` but could not change `PendingIntent` extras with the most up-to-date location variables.

**Questions:**

Is the current implementation the way to go since we don't want to use Google's GCM or FCM?

Answer (score 0):

> however, the postDelay time went from 2 
>   minutes to 7 minutes when device is asleep.

It will go up to several hours, given Doze mode on Android 6.0+.

> tried firing IntentService directly from alarm manager but could not change PendingIntent extras with the most up-to-date location variables.

Use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

> Is the current implementation the way to go?

Polling a server every 30 seconds may result in your users attacking you with machetes for wasting their battery and bandwidth.

> We don't want to use google's GCM or FCM

Then redesign your app to be able to cope with only having server access once every several hours. Then, use `JobScheduler` or things that that wrap around `JobScheduler` (e.g., Evernote's `android-job` library).